# pyyaml support for default list in dataclass?

Tags: python, pyyaml, python-dataclasses

Below is a minimal example that demonstrates the issue.

**First**, imports:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List
import yaml
```

**Next**, define a class that derives from `yaml.YAMLObject`:

```py
@dataclass
class Yaz(yaml.YAMLObject):
    name: str
    items: List[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ['a', 'b', 'c'])
    yaml_tag: str = u'!Yaz'
```

Demonstrate **usage**:

```py
Yaz(name='Yazzzy')  # >>> Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=['a', 'b', 'c'], yaml_tag='!Yaz')
Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=[])  # >>> Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=[], yaml_tag='!Yaz')
```

But sometimes I'd like to **instantiate an instance from a YAML file**. Mock a YAML file:

```py
yaml_str = """---
!Yaz
  name: Yazzzy
"""
```

**Load the YAML file** into an instance:

```py
yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.Loader)  # ERROR!
```

The last line yields the following **error**:

```py
AttributeError: 'Yaz' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Is there some sort of hook I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I am using `Python 3.8` with `pyyaml 6.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I would humbly suggest using the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://github.com/rnag/dataclass-wizard) for this task. It comes with a helper *Mixin class* called the `YAMLWizard`, which you can use along with `pyyaml 6.0`. To clarify it does use `pyyaml` for working with YAML data.

Here's a working example below. Note that I went ahead and removed the `yaml.YAMLObject` and the associated tags in the YAML object, since this is not needed anymore.

I haven't shown this in the example, but it's also possible to load a *nested* dataclass model from YAML using this same approach. You can check out an example of a nested model [here](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_use_cases/wizard_mixins.html#yamlwizard).

```py
from __future__ import annotations  # can be removed in Python 3.9+

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


@dataclass
class Yaz(YAMLWizard):
    name: str
    items: list[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: ['a', 'b', 'c'])


Yaz(name='Yazzzy')  # >>> Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=['a', 'b', 'c'])
Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=[])  # >>> Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=[])


yaml_str = """---
  name: Yazzzy
"""

yaz_object = Yaz.from_yaml(yaml_str)
print(yaz_object)
```

Output:

```
Yaz(name='Yazzzy', items=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: Thanks! If you are the maintainer, please could you add it to anaconda and/or conda forge sources? Thanks again.

Comment: @user18337734 Sure, should hopefully get to it by later today. I haven't published to condo or condo forge before since I haven't use them yet, but I agree it makes sense to have it on platforms aside from pypi, at least for accessibility purposes.

Comment: @user18337734 I managed to publish to anaconda, though it literally took me like 4 hours to figure out how lol. I created a PR to add it to conda-forge but looks like that's still pending for now. Here's the link to Conda for now:  https://anaconda.org/rkvetch/dataclass-wizard

Comment: Good news, this library is now available on conda forge: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/dataclass-wizard